# How to compare an alphanumeric string with a List<string> which also has alphanumeric values C#

Tags: c#, list

I'm unable to figure out how to compare an alphanumeric string with a list string which also has alpanumeric values in it.

*for example :-*

**I have an invoice no : Sales111
to check whether the same invoice exist in database I have written a code for that**

**Here CheckInvoice()  return all invoice no from datatable**

```
 public List<String> CheckInvoice()
        {
            try
            {
                SPDatalogic sp = new SPDatalogic(); //datalogic class
                DataTable dt = new DataTable() ;
                dt = sp.CheckInvoice();
                List<String> list = new List<String>();

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {                    
                    list.Add(dr["invoice_id"].ToString());// column name of invoice no
                }

                return list;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

**Presentation Layer :-**

```
             SPBusinesslogic ab = new SPBusinesslogic(); //businesslogic class
             List<String> inv = new List<String>();
             inv = ab.CheckInvoice();

             if (inv.Any(x => x.Equals(invoiceid_textbox.Text.Trim())))
             {
                        MessageBox.Show("The invoice already exist!");
                    }
```

**What are the ways I can check?
How can I do it without sorting alphabets and numericals?**

Comment: Can you update your question with values returned by `ab.CheckInvoice()`?

Comment: I have no idea what answer you want to hear.

Comment: @RandRandom the code i have written is not working i think there is problem where i am comparing in presentation layer

Comment: @geedubb i have updated! checkInvoice return all invoice no from datatable

Comment: Just as a side note: the approach of loading all the invoice data  will work well at the beginning when there are just a few invoices stored in the database. It would be much more efficient to send the invoice id to the database and check whether a record with that id already exists instead of loading all data. This will scale much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you want use Linq for this simple task? You can simply use `List<T>.Contains(item)` method

```
        List<string> lollipop = new List<string>();
        //Do something
        if(lollipop.Contains("lollipop"))
         //DO something
        else
        //Something else
```

It's more simple and for your problem it's perfect